# prove that the language L = { ww | w ∈ {a,b}* } is not context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, proof-techniques

I came across this question presented in a past exam. I can see why the language is not context free (you can't know what the first w is, hence you are not able to duplicate it, I hope it makes sense), but i would like a more formal way to explain it.
I don't really know where to start, if anyone could give me some advice (anything really) it would be much appreciated.

Thank you all for your time and help :)